# in Kubuntu 17.10, starting Skype, you need to enter the password in the keyring

Tags: ubuntu, skype

I have installed in Kubuntu 17.10 Skype version 8.10.0.4 Calling version 2017.22.01.51 and with the keyring installed, 
I have to enter the password in the keyring window each time when I enter the system ...

If there is a way you configure this keying so that it does not ask for your password? 
This is not configurable anywhere? 
Cromium works the same way ...

I have a desktop login without authorization.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would remove that old skype version and install their new 8.11.0.4

```
apt-cache policy skypeforlinux    #  if its not 8.11.0.4 then purge
sudo apt-get purge skypeforlinux
```

now do a fresh download from https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/
pick the .deb file

```
sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

which will correctly make an entry here so it gets auto updated :

```
grep -r skype  /etc/apt/
```

which should show you this file

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list
```

with contents of

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
```

when you login use your Windows login which is typically your email address, not your skype login ... doing this I get one keychain prompt then all subsequent launches will open up straight away

Alternatively  on linux I find this a very nice stable skype client

https://github.com/stanfieldr/ghetto-skype